# Installed program again in the "available to install" list

Tags: installation, software-center, mysql

I have installed MySQL server and client from Ubuntu software centre.

When I search for them from the dash home, they are listed under "Apps available for download" section.

(If I search and find them in the software centre, I can see the "Installed on ..." message)

Answer (score 0):

yeah they are available for download by you , it means you can install them . they are common to all users of Ubuntu . The free software available for all users . Its not  going to update the list even you already got them your PC . its just something like a menu card example .

even you got them or didnt got them the list wont change . thats the best software list .

Comment: Other applications (such as "main menu"), moved to the "Applications" section after installing them.